# Three.js compass implementation

Tags: three-js, compass

i implemented a compass for my three.js scene based on https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/gpbyw3co/ , but when i rotate object in my scene,the compass is is not showing the north correctly. Now i search for the cause. Could it be:

**1. that i use TrackballControls**

**2. on camera lookAt() is called**

```
this.camera.position.set(7000, 3000, -1750);
this.camera.lookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -1750));
```

**3. on TrackballControls target.set() is called**

```
this.controls.target.set(0, 0, -1750);

this.controls.rotateSpeed = 4;
this.controls.staticMoving = true;
this.controls.noZoom = true;
```

**4. zoom to mouse pointer is implemented**

```
zoomToMousePointer(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var vector = new Vector3();
    var dir = new Vector3();
    var position = this.camera.position;

    var rect = this.renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var left = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var top = event.clientY - rect.top;

    this.camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    vector.set((left / rect.width) * 2 - 1, -(top / rect.height) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    vector.unproject(this.camera);

    var dir = vector.sub(position).normalize();
    let scalar = event.wheelDelta * 4;

    var vector = new Vector3(dir.x * scalar, dir.y * scalar, dir.z * scalar);
    this.camera.position.addVectors(this.camera.position, vector);
    this.controls.target.addVectors(
      this.controls.target,
      vector
    );
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
```

**6. Camera up manipulated**

```
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
```

I use Three.js version 0.105.2
Seems to be the TrackballControls, when i change the fiddle to TrackballControls, compass is not working well anymore:

[image]

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: It seems to be TrackballControls causing, when i use OrbitControls, the code from jsfiddle works for my compass. Any idea, how the angle computation should look like for TrackballControls?